# Gulp Browsersync task not reloading on file changes with new file structure

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, browser-sync, neat

After changing my project to be organized into `src/` and `dist/` folders, my changes aren't being compiled and my browsersync task is no longer reloading the page. If I change the color of a div for instance, the color is not updated even if I stop and restart the gulp task. So my question is, how do I change my gulp tasks to watch for changes in the new file structure I am using, and how do I trigger the reload task once the watch task recognizes a change to a file? I think the reload task works, on a previous working version of this gulpfile `gulp.watch` was working so it doesn't appear to be a problem with that. I tried changing `gulp.watch` to `browserSync.watch` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32988499/731782) answer but that didn't fix it.

I'm guessing this is a problem with my watch task or the browsersync.init but I'm totally stumped.

To be clear, I am making a static webpage using Jade, Bourbon Neat, SCSS, Gulp, and Browsersync.

Here's [a link](https://github.com/OskarRadon/neat-boilerplate) to the full GitHub repo for this project if that helps!

This is my current file structure:

```
/
  dist/
    css/
    js/
    index.html
  node_modules/
  src/
    jade/
    js/
    scss/
  .gitignore
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

And this is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
// VARIABLES

var gulp                    = require('gulp');
var jade                    = require('gulp-jade');
var sass                    = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps              = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer            = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cssmin                  = require('gulp-cssmin');
var neat                    = require('node-neat').includePaths;
var concat                  = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify                  = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename                  = require('gulp-rename');
var browserSync             = require('browser-sync');
var reload                  = browserSync.reload;


// TASKS



// Jade task
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/jade/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({ pretty: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});


// SCSS task
gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed', 
        noCache: true,
        includePaths: neat }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});

// JS task
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'))
});

// Watch files for changes
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('dist/**/*.html', reload);
    gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', ['scss', reload]);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.jade', ['jade']);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['js']);
});

// Start Browsersync server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(['dist/css/**/*.css', 'dist/js/**/*.js'], {
        server: {
            baseDir: "dist/"
        }
    });
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['scss', 'jade', 'js', 'watch', 'browser-sync']);
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988499/731782

Comment: Ooh, no. Thank you, I'll try this and update the question.

Comment: That didn't work :/ I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pulled your repo and made some fixes, will push under the "fixes" branch. Few things:

- Your index.html was referencing your unminified css, while you only exporting minified.
- the watch list needed the subfolders prefxied, so `gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['js']);` and not `gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['js']);`
- Your `browserSync.init` was referencing the wrong directories (src and not dist).

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought I tried all of those changes, but it turns out I didn't try each of them together. You rock! 

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to switch `gulp.watch` to `browserSync.watch`. BrowserSync's documentation indicates that this feature requires at least version 2.6.0. So you may need to update your version of BrowserSync if you are not using that version.